# What are the connections between linear algebra and logic?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, logic

I was wondering whether someone could tell me what connections there are between linear algebra and first order or second order logic, whether it be the model theoretic or proof theoretic component of logic. I am aware of some of the links between algebra and logic,(as discussed here
math.stackexchange.com/questions/199646/…) but I would like to know about the connections in the case of linear algebra. Are there any interesting results in this area?

Comment: "I am aware of some of the links between algebra and logic", which connections are you aware of? Maybe it will help to give an answer to your question here.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199646/the-relation-between-logic-and-algebra for the sorts of connections I had in mind.